# Why is Visual Studio using an old version of TypeScript, even after I update it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I used to compile a web project with Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3) and TypeScript.

I then installed Visual Studio 2015, hoping it would fix other issues I was having. (One being that Build doesn't recompile all .ts files... you have to manually open and save every .ts file you want compiled.) VS 2015 however had "tsc exited with code 1" errors so I reverted to Visual Studio 2013.

However, now Visual Studio 2013 also has the same issue. I enabled verbose output to find this:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.6\tsc.exe --project "F:\depot\depot\code\main\web\CedarsReport\tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles
1>  F:\depot\depot\code\main\web\CedarsReport\error TS5023:Build:Unknown compiler option 'listemittedfiles'.
1>F:\depot\depot\code\main\web\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.3\tools\microsoft.TypeScript.targets(220,5): error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.

Question:

Why is it using TypeScript 1.6? I have formerly installed -- and today re-installed (to be sure) [TypeScript 1.8.5 for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48739).

I'm sure the --listEmittedFiles command is supported in 1.8.5 and not in 1.6. Why is it using a version older than what I just installed?

Comment: Maybe in project are set to 1.6?

Comment: Visual Studio is using the version specified in the project. Different projects may use different language versions, just like they may use different C# versions.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't it. The project file contains <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of the `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` tag in your csproj file and ensure it is set to the correct version (1.8).

If it is not present then you can add it in the first property group.

Comment: It shows <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>. Any other ideas?

Comment: I also see that it is "including" \packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.3\..."

Comment: @VernJensen that means you have version 2.0.3 installed for VS2015. I see you are using a tsconfig.json file, try setting the version in there? (or removing the file completely and specifying the settings in the csproj file)